# PHP Form 'Cool down timer'

Tags: php

Ok basically I have a form that a user submits but I need a 'cool down timer' so that the user cannot submit it again for a given amount of time.
I could not find out how to do this in php which would be preferred if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use session or cookie to store the time of last successful submit and before submit check it you can write in in JS php is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can store in database (example: MySQL) timestamp of last successful submit and on every submit check if value from database + cool down time smaller or equal to current timestamp.
You can get current timestamp in PHP with `time()`.

Comment: Is there a reason why it must specifically be SQL?

Comment: I don't think so, but it is a popular thing so I thought it would be a good example.

Comment: Flatfile is here possible as well!

Comment: @ChristianGärtner Exactly my point! Nobody should assume that everything needs to be done in SQL, even though it may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sessions for that!

When the user submits the form you have to add the timestamp to his sessions:

```
$_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();
```

Now when he submits the form again simply compare the timestamps, e. g. :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['last_submit']) && ((time() - $_SESSION['last_submit']) < 60 * 5)) { //time in seconds! 60 seconds = 1 Minute and 1 minute * 5 = 5 minutes!
    die('Wait a few');
}
$_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();
// regular form processing here!
```

What we do here is to check first: is a previous timestap set? And then if `time() - lastsubmit` is less then  5 minutes.
If these all return true, the form was submitted to "early" and we simply die. If not we refresh the  sessions' s timestamp and can move on.

And of course don' t forget to start the session!

```
session_start();
```

On the very top of the page!

As I' ve read in a comment (thanks again!) a user just could use another browser or clear the cookies. To prevent this (as good as possible) you have to take the IP into account as well.

For this you have to use a server-side database! Store the client' s IP into this database with the timestamp along and then in your if statement you don' t need to get the timestamp from the session, but from the database. Use the client' s IP to get the assoc. timestamp.

Comment: User can user different browsers. Then he can re-submit without waiting.

Comment: Oh darn. Totally forgot about this. Will edit my answer asap.

Comment: Using an IP is not really a good solution, whole office buildings can share 1 IP, hundreds of mobile users may share one external IP etc. A session is closer, but not full proof. Most of the time, making it 'difficult' is enough under normal circumstances. Making it even more difficult would be _requiring_ a user to be logged in, and coupling the timeout to the account rather then the session. However, a user could perhaps create multiple accounts. Which an activation link in an e-mail after registration makes a little bit cumbersome, etc. Not impossible, just a lot of work for the abuser.

Comment: Yeah got that. However the session thing (my first solution) is in most cases sufficent.